# Request Tracker integration with windows active directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, request-tracker

I have installed Request Tracker 3.8.7 on Ubuntu 10.04. I searched a lot of documentation to integrate with Windows Active Directory but did not find proper steps with go head.

Is there any documentation or steps so I can follow it to get successful working. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I think, that everythink you need is on [this URL](http://requesttracker.wikia.com/wiki/ActiveDirectory).

In the short: You will need set RT::Authen::ExternalAuth package, where is a config file, in which you can set authentication against LDAP. AD is technically LDAP... In the sample config file you will have example, how to join authentication against AD.

EDIT: I've search [another wiki article](http://requesttracker.wikia.com/wiki/LdapSiteConfigSettingsForActiveDirectory) from BestPractical...